MissingPluginException when trying to open camera in Flutter on ARM64 Ubuntu machine
I am trying to open the camera and fetch live video, similar to a CCTV camera, on an ARM64-based Ubuntu machine using a Flutter application. However, I am encountering the following error when attempting to access the camera:

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(40)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method availableCameras on channel plugins.flutter.io/camera)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7) 
#1      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:520:35) 
#2      MethodChannelCamera.availableCameras (package:camera_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_camera.dart:66:52) 
#3      main (package:git_camera_example/main.dart:1053:16) 

I've tried using the camera package and various other packages and examples. I even attempted the official example to open the camera provided by Flutter: Flutter Camera Example.
The camera installation is fine and works on the machine, but it's not functioning within the Flutter app. If anyone has a solution or guidance, please help!
Note : I tried flutter_webrtc, which supports Linux, but I am still facing the same error.

This is because the Camera package is not suitable for flutter Linux:


Any other option to stream video?

The error mean that camera package is not provide implementation for Linux. From camera package pub.dev information, this package only support platform:

iOS
Android
Web

as stated in this Github Issue, camera on linux platform support is still on development.
But, if you want to experiment with linux camera, after a quick research i found this camera_linux package. I never use it so i don't know if it's work or not. I recommend you to wait for official flutter support.

I have already tried the camera_linux package; it only supports image capturing and does not support video streaming. I also checked the open issues from its Git repository. Additionally, I am updating my question to mention that I tried flutter_webrtc, which supports Linux, but I am still facing the same error.

i see flutter_webrtc support all platforms so you shouldn't have that error. My blind guess is you're not removed the camera package yet?

As it is ARM64 linux machine, embedded system. That's is way I guess I am getting issue.
